# Format custom textarea field for custom object

Tags: visualforce, custom-object, custom-field, formatting, outputtext

I have a custom object that has a custom field called Notes. The field has the Text Area datatype but when I use it in an outputText as such:

```
<apex:outputText value="{!selectedDetail.Notes__c}"/>
```

It displays as "**Notes** blah blah blah". I would like to get rid of the notes prefix when displaying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try: 
`<apex:outputText value="{!selectedDetail.Notes__c}" label=""/>`